# Encryption and decryption of XML file

Tags: c#

I want to encrypt an XML file and decrypt the same in a different machine in c#. Please help......

I have already tried with RSA algorithm and RijndaelManaged key but not able to decrypt the file in different machine.

Comment: Post your best try and describe the problems you are having with it.

Comment: You've said you've tried it, what? What issues did you encounter? What code did you try and where did it fail? You need to describe your problem in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the problem description, you're probably looking into symmetric encryption algorithm. This is something that should get you started:

```
public class Key {
  public string Password { get; set; }
  public byte[] Salt { get; set; }
  public string Vector { get; set; }
  public PaddingMode? Padding { get; set; }
}

public class AesCryptor {
  private const int HASH_SIZE = 32;
  private ICryptoTransform m_Decryptor;
  private ICryptoTransform m_Encryptor;
  private TimeSpan m_Validity;

  // Methods
  public AesCryptor(Key key, TimeSpan validity) {
    if (key == null) {
      throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
    }
    m_Validity = validity;
    using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged()) {
      aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
      aes.Key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key.Password, key.Salt).GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
      aes.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key.Vector);
      if (key.Padding.HasValue) {
        aes.Padding = key.Padding.Value;
      }
      m_Encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor();
      m_Decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor();
    }
  }

  private static bool CompareArray(byte[] first, byte[] second) {
    if (first.Length != second.Length) {
      return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < first.Length; i++) {
      if (first[i] != second[i]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] encryptedData) {
    byte[] hash;
    if (encryptedData == null) {
      throw new ArgumentNullException("encryptedData");
    }
    byte[] buffer = m_Decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
    using (SHA256 sha = SHA256.Create()) {
      hash = sha.ComputeHash(buffer, 0, buffer.Length - HASH_SIZE);
    }
    byte[] orginalHash = new byte[HASH_SIZE];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, buffer.Length - HASH_SIZE, orginalHash, 0, HASH_SIZE);
    if (!CompareArray(orginalHash, hash)) {
      throw new Exception("Hash match failure.");
    }
    if (m_Validity != TimeSpan.Zero) {
      DateTime timestamp = new DateTime(BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, (buffer.Length - HASH_SIZE) - 8));
      TimeSpan delta = (TimeSpan)(DateTime.Now - timestamp);
      if (delta > m_Validity) {
        throw new Exception("Timestamp too old.");
      }
    }
    byte[] result = new byte[(buffer.Length - HASH_SIZE) - 8];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, result, 0, (buffer.Length - HASH_SIZE) - 8);
    return result;
  }

  public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data) {
    byte[] hash;
    if (data == null) {
      throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
    }
    byte[] buffer = new byte[(data.Length + 8) + HASH_SIZE];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, buffer, 0, data.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks), 0, buffer, data.Length, 8);
    using (SHA256 sha = SHA256.Create()) {
      hash = sha.ComputeHash(buffer, 0, buffer.Length - HASH_SIZE);
    }
    Buffer.BlockCopy(hash, 0, buffer, buffer.Length - HASH_SIZE, HASH_SIZE);
    return m_Encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
  var myKey = new Key {
    Password = "whatever,nevermind@$",
    Vector = "Q^!#g1353hdhjs*-",
    Salt = new byte[] { 0x33, 0x4d, 0x56, 0x4f, 1, 0x22, 15, 0x7f }
  };
  var cryptor = new AesCryptor(myKey, TimeSpan.Zero);
  // this will encrypt c:\test.xml into byte array
  byte[] encrypted = cryptor.Encrypt(File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\test.xml"));
  // this will persist encrypted byte array into file c:\test-encrypted.bin
  File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\test-encrypted.bin", encrypted);
  // this will load & decrypt bytes from file c:\test-encrypted.bin
  byte[] decrypted = cryptor.Decrypt(File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\test-encrypted.bin"));
  // this will write decrypted bytes into c:\test-decrypted.xml
  File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\test-decrypted.xml", decrypted);
```